# Периодическое обновление информации в виджете

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyowm

В данный момент обучаюсь Python и возникла сложность. Есть небольшой виджет погоды. Нужно, чтобы он через n-ое кол-во секунд обновлял информацию. Как это реализовать? Заранее спасибо`

```
owm = pyowm.OWM('87c7712a9b72646a269102230858837b')
observation = owm.weather_at_place("Donetsk")
w = observation.get_weather()
temperature = w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']
status = w.get_status()

root = Tk()
root.title('Погода')
root.geometry('150x100')

label = Label(text='Температура: '+ str(temperature))
label2 = Label(text='Небо: ' + str(status))
label.grid()
label2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6964fca09ad3fb8a405f0e82a0294e72aab284da/tkinter_examples/weather_example.py) обновления данных каждую секунду можно сделать через метод `after`:

```
import pyowm

API_KEY = '87c7712a9b72646a269102230858837b'


def get_weather_info(api_key, place):
    owm = pyowm.OWM(api_key)
    observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
    w = observation.get_weather()
    temperature = w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']
    status = w.get_status()

    return temperature, status


from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Погода')
root.geometry('150x100')

label = Label()
label2 = Label()

label.grid()
label2.grid()


def update_clock():
    temperature, status = get_weather_info(api_key=API_KEY, place='Donetsk')
    print(temperature, status)

    label.configure(text='Температура: ' + str(temperature))
    label2.configure(text='Небо: ' + str(status))

    # Вызов каждую секунду
    root.after(1000, update_clock)


# Сразу вызываем, чтобы виджеты заполнились
update_clock()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**PS.**

`OpenWeatherMap` иногда может кириллицу понимать, поэтому в `place` можно указывать `Донецк` и будет тот же результат

Comment: Спасибо большое. Пойду вникать и разбирать код.